Why doesn't this code type-check in Haskell, given that ((forall b. [b]) -> Bool) is more polymorphic than ((forall a. a) -> Bool)?
I'm working with higher-ranked types in Haskell and based on Peyton Jones'  Practical Type Inference for Arbitrary-Rank Types), I expect the following function to type-check since ((forall b. [b]) -> Bool) appears to be more polymorphic than ((forall a. a) -> Bool).
Here's my code:
fun :: ((forall b. [b]) -> Bool) -> ((forall a. a) -> Bool)
fun arg = arg

However, GHC rejects it with a type error.
I also tried
fun2 :: (forall a.a -> Bool) -> (forall b.[b] -> Bool)
fun2 arg = arg

which compiled successfully, and it is consistent with the fact that (forall a.a -> Bool) is more polymorphic than (forall b. [b] -> Bool). But I do not understand why fun function that I defined previously does not type check.

Turn on DeepSubsumption.

@NaïmFavier Please consider writing an answer.

@NaïmFavier I added

but still it gives me error. Have they simplified subsumption and removed Covariance and contravariance of function types even with DeepSubsumption extension?

Which GHC version? Seems to work fine with all versions that support that extension.

@NaïmFavier That is right, It works. Thank you.

As Naïm Favier says in their comment: "Turn on DeepSubsumption.", this will change the subsumption rules that GHC uses, and thus introduce the deep skolemization:

GHC will instead automatically rewrite expressions like f x of type ty1 -> ty2
to become (\ (y :: ty1) -> f x y)
; this is called eta-expansion. See Section 4.6 of Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types, where this process is called “deep skolemisation”.

which is indeed what the paper "Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types" on page 21 is talking about:

Hence, perhaps we can solve the problem by enriching the definition of subsumption, so that the type systems of Figure 5 and 6 admit the same programs. That is the reason for the new subsumption judgement  ⊢dsk, defined in Figure 7. This relation
subsumes ⊢ol; it relates strictly more types.

